# Config IoT Hub Connection String Error No Iot Hub

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub

I am trying to set up Translator with my MXChip but after I finish the deployment it says "***No IOT Hub***".

I believe this is because of I can not successfully complete "Config IoT Hub Connection String" step. [Details of step in this tutorial](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-iot-workbench/blob/master/docs/iot-devkit/devkit-translator.md#config-iot-hub-connection-string)

What I do in this step is

- I open devkit-traslater\run.csx and fill (string subscriptionKey = "";
  string deviceName = "";) with name and key1 of Translator I get from portal.azure.com
- Then after this step I switch iot Kit into configuration mode.
- Then I follow the steps Config Device Settings but I never receive "The configuration success notification popup bottom right corner once it's done."
  [image: Success popup]

I dont know what I am doing wrong here

Comment: Did you exactly follow these instructions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-dps/how-to-connect-mxchip-iot-devkit? If there is an issue with them, then you should contact MSFT. However, in the general case the documentation should be enough.

Comment: I tried but I receive the same error. No IOT hub. I was wondering now if it is possible to program mxchip without MS IOT?